# How to change the font style of a ListItem?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, qml

In my Ubuntu Touch application, I have a list of items and I would like to highlight some of them by making the text appear in bold (think of unread messages in a mail client).

Looking at the documentation, I didn't find any way of changing the style of the font of a list item (for examle, of a [SingleValue](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.04/Ubuntu.Components.ListItems.SingleValue/) or [Subtitled](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.04/Ubuntu.Components.ListItems.Subtitled/) item).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with the current list items to change the font. The solution for now would be to use an Empty list item and to add a Label inside where you change the font. We are working on completely new list items which will be much faster to create, and which will be more flexible including the possibility to change fonts.